# TableLayout formatting loss after device rotation

Tags: android, layout, rotation, orientation, tablelayout

I'm seeing a strange issue with a TableLayout after the device is rotated from either orientation.  If you load the view in either portrait or landscape mode, the table loads fine.  But once you rotate the device, the columns collapse to just fit their width.  I would expect that after rotation, the columns would still stretch to fit the width of the screen.  Any ideas on what can be done to resolve this?  Screenies and layout code below.

Before Rotation:

[before rotation http://dl.dropbox.com/u/334957/normal_from_portrait.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/334957/normal_from_portrait.png)

After Rotation:

[after rotation http://dl.dropbox.com/u/334957/after_rotate_portrait.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/334957/after_rotate_portrait.png)

Table Layout:

```
    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/dataTable"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_below="@id/chart"
 android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:padding="6dip"
 >  
 </TableLayout>
```

Table Row:

```
    <TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
          <TextView android:id="@+id/col1"
          android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
          android:textColorLink="#FF21759b"
          android:text="Column 1"
          android:padding="4dip"
          android:textColor="#FF464646"/>
          <TextView android:id="@+id/col2" android:text="Column 2"
          android:textColor="#FF464646"
          android:padding="4dip"/>
</TableRow>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Checked today on a 2.2 Nexus One, and it doesn't have this issue.  Could be a bug on devices <= 2.1 that Google fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the same as here [Buttons in TableLayout cropped on Android 1.6 and 2.1 (but not on 1.5 or 2.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436832/buttons-in-tablelayout-cropped-on-android-1-6-and-2-1-but-not-on-1-5-or-2-2/3597481#3597481)