# Buttons in TableLayout cropped on Android 1.6 and 2.1 (but not on 1.5 or 2.2)

Tags: android, tablelayout

I have four buttons arranged in a 2x2 TableLayout.  These buttons each have an image on the left and some text.  The buttons display fine in the emulator for 1.5, and for 2.2, but when testing with 1.6 the two buttons in the righthand column are cropped so that they are missing their righthand edge (the padding to the right of the text is missing and the button ends abruptly with squared off corners rather than rounded ones).  There is plenty of room for the TableLayout to expand to accommodate the full width of the buttons.  This happens for all screen sizes.

The layout looks like this and itself appears within a RelativeLayout:

```
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/buttons"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:paddingTop="10dp">
  <TableRow>
    <Button android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="@style/LaunchButton"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/button1"
            android:text="@string/button1"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="@style/LaunchButton"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/button2"
            android:text="@string/button2"/>
  </TableRow>
  <TableRow>
    <Button android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="@style/LaunchButton"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/button3"
            android:text="@string/button3"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/button4"
            style="@style/LaunchButton"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/button4"
            android:text="@string/button4"/>
  </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

The buttons are styled as follows:

```
<style name="LaunchButton">
  <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
  <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
  <item name="android:gravity">fill_horizontal</item>
  <item name="android:textSize">24dp</item>
  <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

I'm assuming this is a 1.6-specific bug.  Has anybody else come across this problem?  Any suggestions for work-arounds?

**EDIT:** I've had the opportunity to try it with Android 2.1 (both on the emulator and a device), and the problem happens there too.  So 1.5 good, 1.6 bad, 2.1 bad, 2.2 good.

Comment: The easiest work-around for now is to specify a fixed button width rather than setting it to "wrap_content" and letting the layout figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also ran into the same problem on 1.6 and 2.1 but not on 1.5 nor 2.2.

I use `LineraLayout` and set its weight instead and skip the problem using `TableLayout`.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
```