# Android layout bug in 1.6 vs 2.2

Tags: android, user-interface

I have a strange "bug" in my layout file. I am new to Android, so perhaps I am missing something. I stripped the example down to the bare minimum to ease your understanding of the problem:

I have a simple list, with a ListAdapter, which should display a line of text with an icon next to it. The icon should be centered vertically if the text is higher then the icon.

If I leave the attribute "center" out, the sample works (the list item gets the correct heigth), but as soon as I include it, I get a bug.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue? (btw, I need the tableLayout for streching columns, not sure if there is another way for this)

The XML source for the row looks like this:

```
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="1">
<TableRow>

    <TextView
            android:height="30dp"
            android:width="30dp"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            />

    <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="@color/yellow"
            android:id="@+id/simple_list_row_text1"/>

</TableRow>
```

The desired result (which works on higher versions of android without any problems) is:

[image: working]

And the image on Android 1.6

[image]

Comment: is this a Xperia Mini/Pro running 1.6? (just asking, not specific to question)

Comment: Its a Xperia X8, and I just found a solution, see own answer to post :-)

Answer (score 0):

Give the whole TableRow a center_vertical gravity. And of course move the fixed width/height from the TextView to the TableRow, and leave the TextView to wrap_height

Comment: No. the fixed height of the textview (the first one) is only to simulate, normally there is an image with fixed width and height. I will try the first one though.

Comment: No, does not work. I think its a bug, see also here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436832/buttons-in-tablelayout-cropped-on-android-1-6-and-2-1-but-not-on-1-5-or-2-2

Comment: Now I remember that there was some annoying thing with the Tables, maybe it was  that (I very rarely use them so I am not sure). You can replace the table layout with a vertical linear that contains horizontal linears (for rows) - I always use this. And your code doesn't need the second linear, change it with the one from my answer (Table Row will become the single Linear). Of course do this if you want to have one less linear, not that there is something wrong with your code

Answer (score 0):

Solution workaround is:

```
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@color/yellow"
        android:id="@+id/simple_list_row_text1"/>
```